# Trigger typescript compile-on-save from chrome devtools

Tags: visual-studio, ide, typescript, google-chrome-devtools

I'm debugging and editing my .ts files on the fly using Chrome devtools (when debugging).

One of the major drawbacks doing so is that in order to reflect changes of .ts files in associated .js files, I must switch back to Visual Studio, click on "yes, reload" and trigger another save of each modified file (in order to rebuild js), and only then i can come back to my page and F5 it.

Is there a way to tell VS (or chrome, btw) to automatically compile TS files when they're saved ?

**edit** i'm using chrome workspaces to sync files with disk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to tell VS (or chrome, btw) to automatically compile TS files when they're saved ?

If you use chrome workspaces, it will load the ts files from disk instead of in memory. That way when you save a file it is saved to disk. This means you can wire up something like https://github.com/TypeStrong/grunt-ts to compile on save to get the new JS which then can be live reloaded

Comment: Compile on *external save* is not supported by visual studio. You will need something like grunt or gulp or something.

Comment: Does grunt-ts play well with VS compilation ? I dont want to get rid of VS compile on save feature (which is great to report errors directly in VS when not debugging in Chrome)

Comment: Yes. If the settings are the same, the output will be the same. They don't fight